# Was the counting of the Children of Israel David's fault or Yoav's fault?

Tags: tanach, king-david

In the book of Shmuel Book 2, chapter 24, David commands Yoav to count the children of Israel. David later realizes that he made a mistake. Shouldn't this been Yoav's mistake for not doing the task of counting them properly? He could've used the proper method that Moshe used when G-d commanded him to count Israel with the shekel, and yet David takes the blame.  Source: http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16547/jewish/Chapter-27.htm#showrashi=true

Why does the writer blame David for the improper way of counting Israel?
 Shouldn't it have been Yoav's fault (in the writers mind)?

Now here's a little difference of opinion:

In book 1 of Divrei Hayamim, chapter 27, the writer blames Yoav for this..
it seems like there's a difference of opinion between both writers of both books.
Book 2 of Shmuel, blaming  the sin on David.
And Book 1 of Divrei Hayamim blaming it on Yoav.

Who is to blame for not properly counting the Children of Israel?

Comment: Consider narrowing the question so it is more readily answerable. The seeming contradiction between Chronicles and Samuel is a fine question in and of itself. || This is distinct from asking what the writer for Chabad thought. That is something we can't necessarily know. || And that is distinct from simply asking whether or not David was to blame for Yoav's behaviour, and if so why he was to blame, which is also a fine question.

Comment: Perhaps Yoav thought that David had made a psak that it was permitted?

Comment: If you have access to Art Scrolls Sefer Shmu'el, I think he discusses this scenario at length, and he might answer the question.

Comment: Relevant is Kiddushin 42b-43a regarding appointing someone to do a sin for you. This discussion is notably absent from that Gemara, but perhaps the commentators there address this.